# Can you have SLA on an azure worker role with one instance?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-vm-scale-set

From what I know MS Azure guarantees SLA 99.95% for worker role when there is more than one instance (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/cloud-services/v1_5/).

However I also do know that SLA 99.9% is guaranteed for a single VM in case it uses premium storage (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/virtual-machines/v1_6/).

Based on this logic, if a worker role is deployed on one instance which uses premium storage shouldn't the SLA be guaranteed for that instance? I am following the same logic which applies to VM sets (having a single VM with premium storage in VM set..).

Comment: highly doubt that

Comment: do you have any reason?

Comment: because its PaaS and has nothing to do with individual VM sla. I'm not saying i'm 100% right (that why this is a comment, not an answer). but this is my expectation based on 4 years of Azure experience

Answer (score 0):

SLA for PaaS instances not the same as the SLA for individual VMs.

You can check each of the SLA for a specific service here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/legal/sla/